# Entitlement Trigger Deployment issue

Tags: trigger, change-set

I have a trigger on Entitlement object. I have written the test class for the same in Sandbox while deploying the whole bunch to production instance getting Code coverage failure saying **The following triggers have 0% code coverage. Each trigger must have at least 1% code coverage.**

While validating the changeset I have chosen option Run Specific test class including the test class for the Trigger. Just to add more information around the same, I am enhancing the trigger which is already deployed in past. I am not sure about the test class for previous functionality. Though, I have added few test method to cover the previously written stuff.

If there are any additional steps needs to perform for deploying Entitlement trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more on deployment issue related to the Entitlement trigger. Deploying the trigger via **Ant or Eclipse IDE** with all related dependencies will resolve your issue. I have faced this issue in past and Ant worked for me.